# search in listview (custom adapter)

Tags: android, listview

I would like to implement a search in my Listview , I tried a lot but I have not found any soluzine working with my codes !
Can you help me? or in the case show me alternative methods ?
Thanks for your help!

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;

private String[] url;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, int mylist, String[] itemname, String[] url) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.url= url;

}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);

    extratxt.setText("Ricetta " + itemname[position]);

    Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load(url[position])
            .fit() // will explain later
            .transform(new RoundedTransformation(5, 0))
            .centerCrop()
            .into(image);

   return rowView;

   };

}
```

I can not put the main acitivity

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure if I understood what you want to do. So, you have a list where you display some info... Do you have a search field where a user could enter something? Do you want to update the items from the list according to that input from the user?

Comment: Here is well explained functionality to add a search option in listview: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: I had an edit text that gas the function to search in the listview and show the result.

Comment: I did look the link of android hive, but you van noto to do with a custom lista adapter ad my code!